# Why does my code to reverse a Linked List only return the first node?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to `reverse a linked list` with the following code. I have traced it out on paper and it seems to work, but it is failing most tests- can someone let me know where it is going wrong please?

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None




def reverseLinkedList(head):
        curr,prev,nex = head,None,head.next
    
        while nex:
            curr.next = prev 
            prev = curr
            curr = nex 
            nex = nex.next 

        return curr
```

Comment: Is your reverseLinkedList function supposed to be a method of the LinkedList class?

Comment: Sorry, no it is not- I've changed it in the above!

Comment: But still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your while loop exits, curr.next is still None, therefore it is returning only the head of the reversed linked-list.
Just add a line `curr.next = prev` after the while loop, then it will work fine.
So the code of the reverseLinkedList function will be:

```
def reverseLinkedList(head):
    curr,prev,nex = head,None,head.next
    while nex:
        curr.next = prev 
        prev = curr
        curr = nex 
        nex = nex.next 
    curr.next = prev
    return curr
```

**Example for better explaination:**

Let's assume our linked-list is: 1 --> 2 --> 3
After execution of code linked-list becomes: 1 <-- 2   3 <-- curr
There is no link between 2 and 3, but your prev is pointing to 2.
so executing a line `curr.next = prev` will make the linked list:
1 <-- 2 <--3 <--curr

Comment: Thanks Mayank, I don't know how I missed this.. I traced it out like 20 times on paper. But now that you've explained it, it seems so obvious.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's multi-variable assignments to implement the reversal (you just have to be careful with the order of variables):

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value) + (self.next and f"-->{self.next}" or "")

def reverseLinkedList(head):
    newHead = None
    while head:
        newHead,newHead.next,head = head,newHead,head.next
    return newHead
```

Output:

```
h = t = LinkedList(1)
for v in range(2,10):
    t.next = LinkedList(v)
    t = t.next
    
print(h)
1-->2-->3-->4-->5-->6-->7-->8-->9

rh = reverseLinkedList(h)
print(rh)
9-->8-->7-->6-->5-->4-->3-->2-->1
```